# How can I calculate the thickness of a set of strokes in an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How can I calculate the thickness of each stroke in the attached image?

[image]

I did a segmentation for all the nerves in the image and I labelled each object in the image. What I want is to know how to calculate the thickness of each nerve? Also, how can I highlight a specific part of the nerve if there is an inflation in any nerve?

Your help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: there is no image sorry

Comment: @Benoit_11 - A link was found in the post if you clicked on Edit.... the OP just didn't bother to show it lol.

Comment: hahaha that's funny @rayryeng thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @Alaa do you have to use Matlab? You might want to consider using [imageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/), a freeware very simple to use that would fit perfectly (in my opinion) for this task.

Comment: Maybe you could show us non-neuro-nervy-surgeon-folk how an inflation looks - a big red circle around one would do the trick for me ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to point you to the following post: [Measuring the average thickness of traces in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735748/measuring-the-average-thickness-of-traces-in-an-image) .  Essentially, there is a single stroke in an image and the objective is to determine the average thickness of this stroke.  We simply have to reapply this algorithm for each stroke that exists in your image.

The basic algorithm is the following (and very ingenious):

1. For a stroke in your image, apply a [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) to your image where the image is transformed so that all background pixels become white and the object pixels become black.  Hence, we are applying the distance transform on the **inverse** of the image.

   The distance transform finds the distance between a point in your image to the closest non-zero pixel.  As such, by applying the distance transform to the inverse, for each stroke point, this will determine the distance from that particular point to the closest **boundary** point on the stroke.  The reason why we need the distance transform in this aspect will be made clear in the next step.
2. The points on the stroke that share the greatest distance in the distance transform define **the middle** of the stroke.  You can think of this as the **half-way** point in between the stroke.  Collect all of those distance values within some tolerance of this greatest distance due to floating point arithmetic.
3. Find the average or median of all of these said distances and this determines the width of **half** the stroke.... so if you want the **full** thickness, simply multiply the result by 2.

Before I continue, I'm going to assume you have access to the Image Processing Toolbox, as the distance transform is implemented in the [`bwdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) function that is part of the toolbox.  If you don't have this toolbox, then unfortunately what I have written will not work.  This is the only dependency that the algorithm needs (other than using `imread` and `im2bw` of course).

I had to convert your image to binary as you uploaded the image in RGB format for some reason, so I made it into a single channel binary image.  As such, your code could look something like this:

```
%// Read the image from StackOverflow and convert to binary
im = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/DggWW.jpg'));

%// Find all unique contours and assign them a unique ID.  Also determine how many there are
[lbl,N] = bwlabel(im);

%// Initialize an array that determines the thickness of each stroke
thickness = zeros(N,1);

%// Tolerance to collect distances
tol = 1;

%// For each stroke...
for idx = 1 : N

    %// Step #1
    cntr = lbl == idx; %// Get a mask that segments out that stroke only
    d = bwdist(~cntr); %// Find distance transform on inverse

    %// Step #2
    max_dist = max(d(:)); %// Get the maximum distance from stroke to edge
    dists = d(abs(d - max_dist) <= tol); %// Collect those distances within a tolerance

    %// Step #3
    thickness(idx) = 2*mean(dists);  %// Find the average width and multiply by 2 for full width
end
```

`thickness` is an array of elements where it tells you the width or thickness of each stroke in your image.  Each element `i` tells you the thickness of the contour specified by label `i` from the `bwlabel` result.  Therefore, for each element `i` in `thickness`, this records the thickness for the stroke delineated at:

```
cntr = lbl == i;
```

With your image, I get the following result:

```
thickness =

    3.3555
    3.2494
    3.1545
    3.1773
    3.3282
    3.2607
    3.2710
    3.2772
    3.2948
    3.1607
```

As for determining whether or not nerves are inflamed, you would need to know what the ground truth thickness is for each stroke and determine if there is an increase.  I don't have such information, so I'm going to leave that to you as an exercise.  We've calculated the thickness of each stroke so from there, write some code that detects an increase and act accordingly.

---

As an additional bonus, let's make a new output image where we find the centroid of each stroke, place that stroke in this output image and print out its thickness at the centroid of the stroke.  Something like this:

```
imshow(im); hold on;
for idx = 1 : N
    [y,x]= find(lbl == idx);
    cen = mean([x y]);
    text(cen(1), cen(2), ['T = ' num2str(thickness(idx))], 'color', 'red');
end
```

We get:

[image]

Comment: wow I just made this question a favorite haha very nice! +1 of course.

Comment: @MarkSetchell coming from you that means a lot! Thank you!

Comment: Hm. I feel the idea, but something about the math is fishy... I can't quite put my finger on it, but here is an example image that shows what I mean: `http://i.imgur.com/axg4GBw.png` Results should be `1:10`, instead it produces: `[0.0167, 0.0333, 2.6667, 3, 4.6667, 5, 6.6667, 7, 8.6667, 19]` ( `im = padarray(im,[1,1]);` could remove the `19` problem; for the other stuff I have no idea.)

Comment: @knedlsepp I'm confused with your example. Are the black stripes what you want to measure or the white stripes?

Comment: The white ones. Should be vertical lines of thickness `1:10`

Comment: @knedlsepp I'll have to see when I get to work but I compared with what I got with the source post and I matched the output. For now I'm going to leave it as it is.

Comment: @rayryeng: For larger strokes the error should become relatively small. But as the OP's features are of size 3-4 pixels, I think there is some problem with the current implementation.

Comment: @knedlsepp - Yeah, you'll most certainly need to pad the image to get rid of that problem at the end of the array because I assume that the stroke is surrounded by background pixels so nice catch there.  The other problems I'm going through them right now.

Comment: I'll have a look if I can pin down the problem. Here is another test image if you want something to do the debugging with:  http://i.imgur.com/QRuGR3Q.png
pencil strokes are of thicknesses `1:7` (I know the image compression of imgur messed those up a bit, but doing a `im2bw(imread` reconstructs my original bmp.)

Comment: @knedlsepp - It probably has something to do with the tolerance.  I most likely made it too large.  Decreasing it seems to help, but I'm getting `[2,2,4,4,6,6....]`.  I'm going through the output incrementally to see what's up.  Thanks for the debugging image.

Comment: @knedlsepp - D'oh.  This obviously won't work for single pixel strokes.  The half-way point would be the same as the thickness.

Comment: @knedlsepp - Yeah there will most definitely be some inaccuracy depending on whether the stroke has even or odd pixels.  For example, if we had a stroke of size 3, doing what I suggested would mean that the distance transform has an output of 2 along the centre.  Ideally, you would simply collect the twos and the average would be two and multiplying by 2 would be 4... but the stroke should be 3.  So there will most certainly be inaccuracy there... and also this won't work if there is a stroke of a single pixel thickness.

Comment: @knedlsepp - Either way, I'll leave this for now and I'll mull it over, but FWIW I did a lot more than what was deserved for the OP!

Comment: @rayryeng: That's for sure!

Comment: @knedlsepp - lol thanks.  BTW, I do appreciate you checking over my work.  It's one of my faults where I'm excited to get something working and I'll post it without thoroughly checking for corner cases.  You've certainly found at least two of them.

Comment: This is again a perfect example of what I meant last time: The problem is interesting, the solution is highly nontrivial and you wrote an elaborate answer. ;-)

Comment: @AlaaAlwaisy - My pleasure!  Also look at knedlsepp's solution because we both encountered a couple of hiccups with my method.  Also, be aware that you won't get it as accurate if you were to measure out the width yourself.  I would say you would get it within a couple of pixels worth of error.

Comment: @AlaaAlwaisy - You can't accept both of our answers so make sure you choose the answer that helped you the most and stick with that.

Answer (score 2):

My approach solves this problem using the following

### Idea:

For each single stroke in the picture:

1. Compute area of stroke
2. Compute length of stroke
3. Compute average thickness as area divided by stroke length

### Area:

Computing the area is easy. One could simply count the pixels.

### Stroke length:

The stroke length is more difficult. One may be able to use the skeleton of the image `bwmorph(BW,'skel',Inf)` to do this, I however use a different approach. I find the perimeter of the stroke and use some math to find a rectangle of equivalent area and perimeter, the sides of which should correspond to stroke length and average thickness.

Computing the perimeter of such a stroke, one has to pay close attention to the [coastline paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox). Measuring the actual perimeter of the stroke defined by the outline of the pixels will give inaccurate results: The perimeter of a diagonal stroke would be measured as 1 pixelwidth to the right, 1 pixelwidth up, 1 pixelwidth to the right, 1 pixelwidth up, ... instead of: `sqrt(2)` pixelwidths diagonally, ...

We can solve this problem by using [alpha shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) to triangulate our stroke. I use the implementation by *Jonas Lundgren* on the File Exchange: [**`alphavol`**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28851-alpha-shapes).

### Final code:

```
image = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/DggWW.jpg'));    
alphaRadius = 2; %// Could be chosen larger than 2 to get better results, but must not affect the overall area of the triangulation.
%%
[Labeled,N] = bwlabel(image);
thicknesses = zeros(1,N);
lengths = @(Points) sqrt(sum(Points.^2,2));                           

%// Formula for finding an equivalent rectangle:
%// Assume rectangle: Area = a*b, Perimeter = 2*(a+b),
%// solve for a and b, return minimum as thickness
solveForThickness = @(P,A) min(P/4 + (P^2/4 - 4*A)^(1/2)/2, ...
                               P/4 - (P^2/4 - 4*A)^(1/2)/2);
for idx = 1:N
    %// Get current stroke
    stroke = (Labeled == idx);
    [Y,X] = find(stroke);
    %// Get corners of pixels and generate alpha shape
    P = [X-1, Y-1; ...
         X,   Y-1;
         X-1, Y;
         X,   Y];
    [area,S] = alphavol(P,alphaRadius);
    area = nnz(stroke); %// Seems to give better results than triangulated area above
    %// Compute perimeter and thickness
    perimeter = sum(lengths(P(S.bnd(:,1),:)-P(S.bnd(:,2),:)));
    thicknesses(idx) = solveForThickness(perimeter, area);
end
```

### Aftermath:

Keep in mind that this solution will largely depend on how well the triangulation fits the stroke data. The problems of this algorithm due to the coastline paradox will be visible by choosing strokes of uniform varying steepness. There might be a better method to compute the length of the stroke to get more accurate results. It seems to work quite well though.

An alternative to using alpha shapes could be:

```
perimeter = getfield(regionprops(stroke,'perimeter'),'Perimeter');
```

The results of which are also quite accurate.

Comment: My friend 
I'd like to ask you about (alphavol) function I did not find it in Matlab ???

Comment: It's on MATLAB's FEX: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28851-alpha-shapes . BTW +1 for you knedlsepp

Comment: @rayryeng: Thanks! I couldn't figure out how to fix the `bwdist` solution, so I thought I'd try something different. It actually performs quite well with the test cases I uploaded.

Comment: I don't know if I trust the idea, because there are an infinite number of possible outputs for perimeters given some area. Take an area of 16, for example -> (1, 16 => 34), (2, 8 => 20), (4, 4 => 16), (3/2, 32 / 3 => 24).