# How can I find the thickness of a ROI traced via imfreehand in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, roi, thickness

I am faced with a task to take a ROI on an image that was traced via the `imfreehand` function and determine the thickness of that ROI, preferably at all points. Has anyone ever faced similar tasks before, or implemented something like the ImageJ plugin called "Local thickness"? Information on the description and mathematical algorithm can be found [here](http://www.optinav.com/Local_Thickness.htm), with more details under "documentation".

What is the solution?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735748/measuring-the-average-thickness-of-traces-in-an-image) question and answers