# Fast alorithm to approximate the thickness of digit from an image

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, image-processing

I'm learning some C++ and trying to develop a simple software for detecting what kind of
digit has been written by the user.
I have an idea of what I want it to look like, but I have no clue how to get through measuring the thickness of a digit. The measurement doesn't need to be very accurate, a couple of pixels too many or not enough do not really matter. 

Sample iamge looks like this:
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRmyi.png)

The image is always cropped in such a way, that it is the minimum resolution possible. It is saved in grayscale, but the technical details aren't really meaningful here.


So,  is there an efficient algorithm, that can determine the size of the stroke used to draw the image? It would be great if it could process ~100 images /second (from memory).

Comment: Random idea: measure the thickness alongside some random lines and take the median?

Comment: @CorentinPane This is not that bad, I will try to code this today or tomorrow and  try to post the results

Comment: Well I don't think it's that good either haha. What about picking a random white pixel, finding the closest black pixel, and then measure the shortest distance to another white pixel that isn't zero? If you do that at a couple of random places that should give you a nice estimate too. Or you could have a look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735748/measuring-the-average-thickness-of-traces-in-an-image).

Comment: @CorentinPane The accepted answer in your link is the approach I was going to suggest. If you take the global maximum of the distance transform, you'll get a decent measure of the thickness of the stroke.

Comment: Yeah sure but I think that the key is here is efficiency and speed, and it looks like the solutions based on distance to background require a lot of parsing and calculations. How do you quickly evaluate the distance of a point to the background? And the distance of all points to the background? That's why I think that heuristic approaches could work better if speed is preferred over accuracy.

Comment: You could *skeletonize* the image then 'trace' through the skeletal form and count how many pixels are "white" on either side, orthogonal to the current 'direction of travel'. (A bit vague, I know, but it's already past my bedtime!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the area(A) and perimeter(P) of the digit's contour，then width ~= A / (0.5*P).  Note that for digit "4,6,8,9,0" there are holes inside the contours, and the perimeter should include the vaule of holes. (I have also tested the method of skeletonization, i.e. width ~= [area of object] / [area of skeleton]. The result is better, but the skeletonization implementation found in github is time-consuming.)

The code is shown below, and it is fast enough.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "digit_width.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // string filename = "all.jpg";
    string filename = "SRmyi.png";
    Mat img_raw = imread(filename, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    threshold(img_raw,img_raw,128,255,THRESH_BINARY);
    vector<double> width_list;
    vector<Point2f> center_list;

    digit_width(img_raw, width_list, center_list);

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < width_list.size(); idx++)
    {
        cout << width_list[idx] << endl;
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << setprecision(4) << width_list[idx];
        putText(img_raw, oss.str(), center_list[idx], FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1.0, 128);
    }

    imwrite("new_"+filename, img_raw);
    imshow("img",img_raw);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

**digit_width.hpp**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void digit_width(const Mat & img_bin, vector<double>& width_list, vector<Point2f>& center_list)
{
    vector<std::vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    findContours(img_bin, contours, hierarchy, RETR_CCOMP, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );

    vector<vector<int> > contours_child;
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < hierarchy.size(); idx++)
    {
        if(hierarchy[idx][3] == -1)
        {
            vector<int> child;
            child.push_back(idx);

            if(hierarchy[idx][2] != -1)
            {
                int child_idx = hierarchy[idx][2];
                child.push_back(child_idx);
                while(hierarchy[child_idx][0] != -1)
                {
                    child_idx = hierarchy[child_idx][0];
                    child.push_back(child_idx);
                }
            }

            contours_child.push_back(child);
        }
    }

    for(size_t idx = 0; idx < contours_child.size(); idx++)
    {
        double width = 0;

        double perimeter = arcLength(contours[ contours_child[idx][0] ], true);
        double area = contourArea(contours[ contours_child[idx][0] ]);

        auto M = moments(contours[ contours_child[idx][0] ]);
        float cX = M.m10 / M.m00;
        float cY = M.m01 / M.m00;
        Point2f pt = Point2f(cX, cY);


        if( contours_child.size() > 1 )
        {
            for(size_t jdx=1; jdx<contours_child[idx].size(); jdx++)
            {
                perimeter += arcLength(contours[ contours_child[idx][jdx] ], true);
                area     -= contourArea(contours[ contours_child[idx][jdx] ]);
            }
        } 

        width = area / (0.5 * perimeter);
        width_list.push_back( width );
        center_list.push_back(pt);
    }

}
```

The results are shown below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What an interesting approach! I will surely try this out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when I paste the number 2 image into the Paint 3D (Windows), it requires a pen of size 20 - 21 to fill the stroke. I've been playing around and here what I've come up with. Although it needs some improvements for production (left it for you :) ), it works for me. It assumes that the pallet is black and the stroke is white, but you can change it all later to the behavior you want. You can also implement diagonal scanning for it to yield better results.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")
#include<gdiplus.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace Gdiplus;

void ProcessImageXY(bool isX, Bitmap *bitmap, int width, int height, int* arr) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        Color clr;
        bool counting = false;
        int countpx = 0;
        int avcountpx = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            if (isX)
                bitmap->GetPixel(x, y, &clr);
            else
                bitmap->GetPixel(y, x, &clr);
            if (clr.GetValue() == Color::White) {
                counting = true;
                countpx++;
            }
            else {
                if (counting == true) {
                    counting = false;
                    if (avcountpx == 0)
                        avcountpx = countpx;
                    else
                        avcountpx = (avcountpx + countpx) / 2;
                    countpx = 0;
                }
            }
            arr[y] = avcountpx;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    GdiplusStartupInput si;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &si, NULL);
    Bitmap *bitmap = Bitmap::FromFile(L"C:\\Users\\art_g\\Desktop\\nWr3O2.png");
    auto width = bitmap->GetWidth();
    auto height = bitmap->GetHeight();
    int* strokepx = new int[width + height];
    ProcessImageXY(true, bitmap, width, height, strokepx); // horizontal scan
    ProcessImageXY(false, bitmap, height, width, strokepx + height);    //vertical scan
    // to measure diagonal lines, need to implement diagonal scans
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    int* distinctnmrs = new int[width + height];
    int distwidth = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height + width; i++)
    {
        bool present = false;
        for (int c = 0; c < distwidth; c++) {
            if (strokepx[i] == distinctnmrs[c]) {
                present = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!present)
            distinctnmrs[distwidth++] = strokepx[i];
    }
    int result = 0;
    int maxhits = 0;
    for (int i = 0, hits = 0; i < distwidth; i++, hits = 0) {
        if (distinctnmrs[i] == 0)
            continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < height + width; j++) {
            if (distinctnmrs[i] == strokepx[j])
                hits++;
        }
        if (hits > maxhits) {
            maxhits = hits;
            result = distinctnmrs[i];
        }
    }
    int stroke = result;
    cout << stroke << endl;
}
```