# Techniques to make images of handwritten digits similar in thickness?

Tags: image-processing

I'm generating images of handwritten numbers (of more than one digit) by horizontal concatenation images of digits taken from the MNIST dataset, with the goal that the generated numbers look somewhat natural (as in they look like they were written by a person).

For this, I sample one image for each digit from 0-9 from the dataset, and then use those images to generate an image of whatever number I want to.

One issue that I'm facing in this is that in the MNIST dataset, the digits are of varying thickness, so the final number that I generate has some digits that are too bold (as can be seen in the image attached, where the 9 is too bold, and the 5 is the opposite).

[Image of a number generated by the mentioned method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghWCd.png)

What I want to know is whether there is some image processing technique using which I can process all digit images so they have the same or approximately the same thickness (perhaps the thickness can be controlled by some parameters)?

Comment: I've found [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735748/measuring-the-average-thickness-of-traces-in-an-image) that gives an algorithm which uses distance transformation to find the average thickness of a trace. I guess I can use this algorithm to compare the thickness to a thickness parameter and erode/dilate the image based on the result of the comparison. If anyone knows of any better algorithms please post it as an answer or a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was as simple as simply taking the skeleton of the image and then dilating it to whatever thickness I wanted it to be.

This of course only works if the images are entirely composed of very simple curves, which fortunately the MNIST dataset is.